# Changing VScode permissions

Tags: permissions, visual-studio-code, sudo

I am trying to change the permissions in VScode so that I can make commits with my source control system. I want to do this versus doing "sudo git commit, push, etc." from the command line. Right now whenever I try to do anything from the source control panel on the left sidebar it says "permission denied." Is there somewhere in the settings/preferences where I can change this?